# SVG circles piling up in d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, geometry

I am writing a d3 program that reads in stats from NFL teams from a csv file and the user selects the team to view from a dropdown menu. The program then creates circles in the formation of the offense and defense for the stats for that team and displays it. I have the program able to display the some of it so far, but when I select another team, the old circles stay on the screen and the new ones are just appended on top. My question is how do I fix this? I tried adding remove at the end of the below function but it just removes that circle completely

```
function menuChanged() 
{
var selectedValue = d3.event.target.value;
var picked;

for(var i = 0; i < 32; i++)
    if(nest[i].key == selectedValue)
        picked = i;

rT = svg.selectAll("rTcircle")
            .data(nest)
            .enter().append("circle")
            .attr("class", "dot")
            .attr("r", function() { return Math.sqrt(nest[picked].values[0].rushing) * 0.7; })
            .attr("cx", 40)
            .attr("cy", 300)
            .style("fill", function () { return nest[picked].values[0].color1; })
            .style("stroke", function () { return nest[picked].values[0].color2; });
rG = svg.selectAll("rGcircle")
            .data(nest)
            .enter().append("circle")
            .attr("class", "rGdot")
            .attr("r", function() { return Math.sqrt(nest[picked].values[0].rushing) * 0.7; })
            .attr("cx", 190)
            .attr("cy", 300)
            .style("fill", function () { return nest[picked].values[0].color1; })
            .style("stroke", function () { return nest[picked].values[0].color2; });
cO = svg.selectAll("oCcircle")
            .data(nest)
            .enter().append("circle")
            .attr("class", "oCdot")
            .attr("r", function() { return Math.sqrt(nest[picked].values[0].rushing) * 0.7; })
            .attr("cx", 340)
            .attr("cy", 300)
            .style("fill", function () { return nest[picked].values[0].color1; })
            .style("stroke", function () { return nest[picked].values[0].color2; });
lG = svg.selectAll("lGcircle")
            .data(nest)
            .enter().append("circle")
            .attr("class", "lGdot")
            .attr("r", function() { return Math.sqrt(nest[picked].values[0].rushing) * 0.7; })
            .attr("cx", 490)
            .attr("cy", 300)
            .style("fill", function () { return nest[picked].values[0].color1; })
            .style("stroke", function () { return nest[picked].values[0].color2; });
lT = svg.selectAll("lTcircle")
            .data(nest)
            .enter().append("circle")
            .attr("class", "lTdot")
            .attr("r", function() { return Math.sqrt(nest[picked].values[0].rushing) * 0.7; })
            .attr("cx", 640)
            .attr("cy", 300)
            .style("fill", function () { return nest[picked].values[0].color1; })
            .style("stroke", function () { return nest[picked].values[0].color2; });

var oLineT = svg.selectAll(".text")
            .data(nest)
            .enter().append("text")
            .attr("class","text")
            .style("text-anchor", "middle")
            .attr("x", 40)
            .attr("y", 300)
            .style("fill", function() { return nest[picked].values[0].color1; })
            .style("stroke", function() { return nest[picked].values[0].color2; })
            .style("font-family", "verdana")
            .style("stroke-width", 0.7)
            .text(function () {return nest[picked].values[0].team; });

rT.data(nest).transition()
    .duration(500)
    .attr("class", "dot")
    .attr("r", function() { return Math.sqrt(nest[picked].values[0].passing) * 0.7; })
    .attr("cx", 40)
    .attr("cy", 300)
    .style("fill", function () { return nest[picked].values[0].color1; })
    .style("stroke", function () { return nest[picked].values[0].color2; });
rG.data(nest).transition()
    .duration(500)
    .attr("class", "rGdot")
    .attr("r", function() { return Math.sqrt(nest[picked].values[0].passing) * 0.7; })
    .attr("cx", 190)
    .attr("cy", 300)
    .style("fill", function () { return nest[picked].values[0].color1; })
    .style("stroke", function () { return nest[picked].values[0].color2; });
cO.data(nest).transition()
    .duration(500)
    .attr("class", "oCdot")
    .attr("r", function() { return Math.sqrt(nest[picked].values[0].passing) * 0.7; })
    .attr("cx", 340)
    .attr("cy", 300)
    .style("fill", function () { return nest[picked].values[0].color1; })
    .style("stroke", function () { return nest[picked].values[0].color2; });
lG.data(nest).transition()
    .duration(500)
    .attr("class", "lGdot")
    .attr("r", function() { return Math.sqrt(nest[picked].values[0].passing) * 0.7; })
    .attr("cx", 490)
    .attr("cy", 300)
    .style("fill", function () { return nest[picked].values[0].color1; })
    .style("stroke", function () { return nest[picked].values[0].color2; });
lT.data(nest).transition()
    .duration(500)
    .attr("class", "lTdot")
    .attr("r", function() { return Math.sqrt(nest[picked].values[0].passing) * 0.7; })
    .attr("cx", 640)
    .attr("cy", 300)
    .style("fill", function () { return nest[picked].values[0].color1; })
    .style("stroke", function () { return nest[picked].values[0].color2; });

oLineT.data(nest).transition()
    .duration(500)
    .attr("class","text")
    .style("text-anchor", "middle")
    .attr("x", 40)
    .attr("y", 300)
    .style("fill", function() { return nest[picked].values[0].color1; })
    .style("stroke", function() { return nest[picked].values[0].color2; })
    .style("font-family", "verdana")
    .style("stroke-width", 0.7)
    .text(function () {return nest[picked].values[0].team; });
}
```

Comment: start simple with just one circle

Comment: @StephenThomas I did that and I could update it but when I tried to do 2 circles, nothing appeared. With this, I can do the 5 but they continuously append until the program crashes. I'm caught between a rock and a hard place

Answer (score 1):

This is a classic case of not properly defining the "enter" and the 'update" selections (and the "exit", if any). Unfortunately, just quickly skimming your `menuChanged` function, it seems to me that you will have to do a lot of changes, in order to make it the "D3 way". Also, you could store the variable parts in... well, variables!

I made a simple demo to show you how the "enter" and the "update" selections work (I'm using v4 here). First, bind the data:

```
var circles = svg.selectAll(".teamCircles")
    .data(data[0][team].positions);
```

Both "enter" and "update" selections rely on this bound data.

Then, set the "enter" selection (here, I put it inside the `menuChanged` function, but if the number of players never change, it can be outside the function):

```
circlesEnter = circles.enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr("class", "teamCircles")
    .attr("cx", d => d.x)
    .attr("cy", d => d.y)
    .attr("r", 8)
    .attr("fill", data[0][team].color);
```

And, finally, the "update" selection. The update selection only works on previously existing elements:

```
circlesUpdate = circles.transition()
    .duration(1000)
    .attr("cx", d => d.x)
    .attr("cy", d => d.y)
    .attr("r", 8)
    .attr("fill", data[0][team].color);
```

Here is the demo:

```js
var w = 500,
    h = 300;

var svg = d3.select("#svg").append("svg")
    .attr("width", w)
    .attr("height", h);

var data = [{
    "San Francisco 49": {
        color: "red",
        positions: [{
            x: 110,
            y: 50
        }, {
            x: 35,
            y: 56
        }, {
            x: 230,
            y: 200
        }, {
            x: 431,
            y: 50
        }, {
            x: 310,
            y: 250
        }]
    },
    "Green Bay Packers": {
        color: "green",
        positions: [{
            x: 360,
            y: 120
        }, {
            x: 51,
            y: 156
        }, {
            x: 30,
            y: 60
        }, {
            x: 130,
            y: 210
        }, {
            x: 410,
            y: 250
        }]
    },
    "Baltimore Ravens": {
        color: "purple",
        positions: [{
            x: 200,
            y: 200
        }, {
            x: 34,
            y: 236
        }, {
            x: 390,
            y: 98
        }, {
            x: 330,
            y: 66
        }, {
            x: 10,
            y: 210
        }]
    }
}];

d3.select("#selection").on("change", menuChanged);

function menuChanged() {
    var team = this.value;
    var circles = svg.selectAll(".teamCircles")
        .data(data[0][team].positions);

    circlesEnter = circles.enter()
        .append("circle")
        .attr("class", "teamCircles")
        .attr("cx", d => d.x)
        .attr("cy", d => d.y)
        .attr("r", 8)
        .attr("fill", data[0][team].color);

    circlesUpdate = circles.transition()
        .duration(1000)
        .attr("class", "teamCircles")
        .attr("cx", d => d.x)
        .attr("cy", d => d.y)
        .attr("r", 8)
        .attr("fill", data[0][team].color);



}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<select name="select" id="selection">
 <option value="">Select</option>
 <option value="San Francisco 49">San Francisco 49</option>
 <option value="Green Bay Packers">Green Bay Packers</option>
 <option value="Baltimore Ravens">Baltimore Ravens</option>
</select>
<div id="svg"></div>
```

**PS**: by the way, the reason your circles are piling up is because in your enter selections you're selecting something that doesn't exist. For instance:

```
rT = svg.selectAll("rTcircle")
```

`rTcircle` doesn't exist, and thus your enter selection is never empty.